# How to count no. of characters entered in multiline textbox till 140 characters

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to count no. of characters entered in multiline textbox, i wanna enter maximum 140 characters in my multiline textbox using vb.net ...

In short i want textbox to enter limit is only 140 characters ....

i have te following code to do that .... but i wanna implement 140 characters limit in multiline textbox :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function Count(x) {

           document.getElementById("Label1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("TextBox2").value.length;
        }
</script>


<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Height="78px" 
            TextMode="MultiLine" Width="224px" onkeyup="Count(this.id)" 
            MaxLength="140"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Take a look at this article: [Limit the Number of Characters in a Textarea or Text Field](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/form/limit-characters.html)

Comment: +1 I will surely learn something with your question, as not being a Web programmer myself, still learning it.

Comment: Watch your ids... the ASP.Net ID is not necessarily the same as the output HTML id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do this. The function takes the number of characters you're limiting to, the (client, HTML) id of the control to count, and the id of the element to output the count into

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CountChars(charLimit, inputId, outputId) {
        var remainingChars = charLimit - document.getElementById(inputId).value.length;
        document.getElementById(outputId).innerHTML = remainingChars;
    }   
</script>
```

And here's a usage example

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" Width="100%" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="10" MaxLength="140"
        runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</p>
<p>
    Characters remaining: <span id="characterCount">140</span></p>
```

Hook up the event handler in code behind, in the page load event:

```
Protected Sub AddCharCountHandler()
    TextBox2.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "CountChars(" & 140 & ", '" & TextBox2.ClientID & "'," & "'characterCount');")
End Sub
```

Note that I'm calling the function using txtDescription.ClientId, although my output span has a fixed id.

Comment: Its not working the code i provided below is working but .... i wanna limit it to 140 characters only //

Comment: My original example was for 500 chars, just swap out the 500s for 140 and should be fine? I've edited my example now to match. Ah and note I'm giving remaining characters, rather than number used.

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged your question with `asp.net` I'm assuming you're talking about a web application.

If it is so, this job is best done by a client side script like JavaScript, and not VB.NET, you should use the latter to do a server side check only after the user has submitted the form, and use the former while he is still entering the data.

On the internet there are many examples on how to do this, just look for something like "[javascript count characters](http://www.google.it/search?q=javascript+count+characters)".